# Getting both levels of a multi-index to re-index a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to get both levels of a multi-index dataframe so I can re-index a dataframe based on this.

Take a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.date_range('20070101',periods=3200)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0,100,(3200,1)), columns =list('A'))
df['date'] = dates
df = df[['date','A']]
```

Apply season function to the datetime index

```
def get_season(row):
    if row['date'].month >= 3 and row['date'].month <= 5:
        return '2'
    elif row['date'].month >= 6 and row['date'].month <= 8:
        return '3'
    elif row['date'].month >= 9 and row['date'].month <= 11:
        return '4'
    else:
        return '1'
```

Apply the function

```
df['Season'] = df.apply(get_season, axis=1)
```

Create a 'Year' column for indexing

```
df['Year'] = df['date'].dt.year
```

Multi-index by Year and Season

```
df = df.set_index(['Year', 'Season'], inplace=False)
```

Group the data

```
df2 = df['A'].groupby(level=['Year','Season']).mean()
```

When I query this for the first level:

```
df2.index.get_level_values(0)
```

I get the years:

```
Out[4]: 
Int64Index([2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2009, 2009, 2009,
        2009, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012,
        2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2015,
        2015, 2015, 2015],
       dtype='int64', name=u'Year')
```

and the second level:

```
df2.index.get_level_values(1)
```

I get the seasons:

```
Out[6]: 
Index([u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4', u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4', u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4',
   u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4', u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4', u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4',
   u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4', u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4', u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4'],
  dtype='object', name=u'Season')
```

But I want both years and seasons associated with eachother - so I can re-index a dataframe based on both year and season, both levels of the multi-index.

That is - I want `([2007;1 , 2007;2 , 2007;3])` etc.

Is this possible to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> df2.index.tolist()
[(2007, '1'),
 (2007, '2'),
 (2007, '3'),
 (2007, '4'),
 (2008, '1'),
 (2008, '2'),
 (2008, '3'),
 (2008, '4'),
...
]
```

Comment: This works (thanks!) but when I try to reindex a dataframe using this: `df3.reindex(newindex)`gives the error `Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!` - this is probably a separate question...

Comment: Ah - got it `df.loc[newindex]`